# How to pass variable value in feature line in karate?

Tags: karate

Lets say I have a variable which I defined in the background

```
Background: 
* def checkin = '2018-10-05'
```

Now i want my feature line looks like

```
Feature: checkin date is '2018-10-05'
```

I tried

```
Feature: checkin date is '#(checkin)'
```

But its not working.

Comment: accepted previous answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic feature names are not supported.

Sounds you are just trying to get some better formatting in the report ? Use a `Scenario Outline` - so you will see the value of each `Examples` row when it fires.

EDIT: just use `print` and you will see anything you want in the report.

EDIT2: okay this will be possible in the next version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/553

Comment: yes I am trying to get some better formatting in report.Actually I have 10 scenarios under one feature.So is it possible to pass variable name in ```scenario outline``` for eg. ```Scenario Outline: checkin date is '#(checkin)'```

Comment: @GauravKinra I just added a comment, just use the `print` syntax.

Comment: @Joe that's extremely vague :) please ask a new question, and be clear and specific - ideally with a mcve: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example